# IBoutlet Connected From SuperClass UIView Still Nil

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, iboutlet

I work with Nibs. I have two screens that will use the "same" `UIView` component with the same behavior. It's not the same component because in each screen i placed a `UIView` and made the same configuration, as show on the image.

[image: The two Screens]

To solve this and prevent replicate the same code in other classes i wrote one class, that is a `UIView` subclass, with all the functions that i need.

After that i made my custom class as superclass of these `UIView` components to inherit the `IBOutlets` and all the functions.

[image: Added as SuperClass of UIView Components]

[image: Custom superclass add success]

My custom class is not defined in a `Nib`, is only a `.swift` class.

I made all the necessary connections but at run time the `IBOutlets` is `Nil`.

[image: IBOutlets Connected]

[image: Connections on View]

[image: Connections on UITableViewCell]

The code of my custom class:

```
class FeelingGuideView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var firstScreen: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondScreen: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var thirdScreen: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var fourthScreen: UILabel!

    private var labelsToManage: [UILabel] = []
    private var willShow: Int!
    private var didShow: Int!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.initLabelManagement()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.initLabelManagement()
    }

    private func initLabelManagement() {
        self.initLabelVector()
        self.willShow = 0
        self.didShow = 0
        self.setupLabelToShow(label: labelsToManage[0])
        self.setupLabels()
    }

    private func initLabelVector() {
        self.labelsToManage.append(self.firstScreen)
        self.labelsToManage.append(self.secondScreen)
        self.labelsToManage.append(self.thirdScreen)
        self.labelsToManage.append(self.fourthScreen)
    }

    private func setupLabels() {

        for label in labelsToManage {
            label.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
            label.layer.borderColor = UIColor(hex: "1A8BFB").cgColor
        }
    }

    func willShowFeelCell(at index: Int) {
        self.willShow = index

        if willShow > didShow {
            self.setupLabelToShow(label: labelsToManage[willShow])
        }
        else if willShow < didShow {

            for i in didShow ... willShow + 1 {

                let label = labelsToManage[i]
                self.setupLabelToHide(label: label)
            }
        }
    }

    private func setupLabelToShow(label: UILabel) {
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: "1A8BFB")
    }

    private func setupLabelToHide(label: UILabel) {
        label.textColor = UIColor(hex: "1A8BFB")
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }
}
```

I found this question similar to mine: [Custom UIView from nib inside another UIViewController's nib - IBOutlets are nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20014437/custom-uiview-from-nib-inside-another-uiviewcontrollers-nib-iboutlets-are-nil)

But my `UIView` is not in a nib.

**EDIT:**

I overrided the `awakeFromNib` but it neither enter the method.

**More explanation:**

My custom class is only superClass of this component:

[image: Custom UIView]

Which i replicate on two screens.

One screen is a `UITableViewCell` and the another a `UIViewController`.

It's all about to manage the behavior of the labels depending on the screen that is showing at the moment on the `UICollectionView`

When the `initLabelVector()` function is called at the `required init?(coder aDecoder:)` it arrises a unwrap error:

[image: Error]

The error when try to open the `View`:

[image]

Cannot show the error with the `UITableViewCell` because it is called at the beginning of the app and don't appear nothing. To show the error with the screen i needed to remove the call of the `UITableViewCell`.

The `UITableViewCell` is registered first with the `tableView.register(nib:)` and after using the `tableView.dequeueReusebleCell`.

The `UIViewController` is called from a menu class that way:

```
startNavigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: FellingScreenViewController())
appDelegate.centerContainer?.setCenterView(startNavigation, withCloseAnimation: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Perhaps `init(coder:)` is too soon: the view exists but its outlets are not hooked up yet. Try not accessing the view outlets until some later moment of initialization, such as an override of `willMove(toWindow:)` or `didMoveToWindow`. Also I regard your claim that `awakeFromNib` is not called as deeply troubling, since that is the initialization moment I would have tried.

Comment: Thank you, so much! That is exactly the problem. In the init the outlets are not hooked up yet. I called the `initLabelManagement()` func on the parent class in the `viewDidLoad()` and worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this code:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.initLabelManagement()
}
```

The trouble is that `init(coder:)` is *too soon* to speak of the view's outlets, which is what `initLabelManagement` does; the outlets are not hooked up yet. Put this instead:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.initLabelManagement()
}
```

---

#### How I arrived at this answer:

As a test, I tried this:

```
class MyView : UIView {
    @IBOutlet var mySubview : UIView!
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)
        print(#function, self.mySubview)
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        print(#function, self.mySubview)
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
init(coder:) nil
awakeFromNib() <UIView: 0x7fc17ef05b70 ... >
```

What this proves:

- `init(coder:)` is *too soon*; the outlet is not hooked up yet
- `awakeFromNib` is *not* too soon; the outlet *is* hooked up
- `awakeFromNib` *is called*, despite your claim to the contrary

Comment: `setupLabels()` (messaged from `initLabelManagement()`) also works with the layer, which frame probably isn't calculated yet at `awakeFromNib()`. Isn't that supposed to be done on `layoutSubviews()` or something similar?

Comment: @AlejandroIván My concern is not with that. The OP asked why there was a "`nil` when unwrapping an Optional" error when speaking of the outlet property in `init(coder:)` and I answered that. The advisability of the entire approach being taken here is outside the scope of this discussion.

Answer (score 1):

When the `init()` from my custom class is called the `IBOutlets` are not hooked up yet.

So, I created a reference on the parent view and called the `iniLabelManagement()` from the `viewDidLoad()` method and everything worked.

Thank you matt, for the help and patience!

Comment: Very good, but of course you have now violated the encapsulation of the view class. It would be better to figure out when the view itself can guarantee that its outlets are hooked up. That is exactly what I thought `awakeFromNib` would be.

Comment: Thank you, i will try it. When i do it, i will atualize the answer.

Comment: I have added an answer proving that `awakeFromNib` should be called and that it is the right moment to start talking about the view's outlets.